# Field Name in Jackson parser Error Message

Tags: jackson

I am using Data Binding option to convert the JSON string to POJO. When I pass a wrong value for a field the Jackson parser dosen't give the field name in the error.

Here is an example, I have a field named `taxAmt` which is of type Double in my JSON, when I pass any integer value in the `taxAmt` field every thing works fine. But when I pass a non-integer value in `taxAmt` like `taxAmt:abcd`.

Parser throws a error message saying

> org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Is there anyway to have the parser to append the field name in the error message, so that it will be easy for the caller to identify the field which has the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not with data-binding (which would indicate property that has problem), but rather that you seem to be forgetting double-quotes around String value. JSON requires you to quote Strings, so parser throws an exception at point where it notices the issue.

It might make sense to improve the error message however, given that parser does know the path to that point... hmmh.

Comment: taxAmt is an integer that's why i didn't enclose them with double-quote. As you mentioned I tried to wrap them with double-quote like "taxAmt":"adfasf" in this case it did point me to the right filed name in the error message. Is there way achieve this without the double-quote?